# Can not run Elastic Search on ubuntu (Error opening log file)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, terminal

I have problems with running Elastic Search on my ubuntu 20.04 server (I can do it locally). When I run  `./bin/elasticsearch` in terminal I get lines below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]
output:
[0.000s][error][logging] Error opening log file 'logs/gc.log': Permission denied
[0.001s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=logs/gc.log' using options 'filecount=32,filesize=64m' failed.
error:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Could not rename log file 'logs/gc.log' to 'logs/gc.log.05' (Permission denied).
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.flagsFinal(JvmOption.java:119)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.findFinalOptions(JvmOption.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:38)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:135)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:86)
```

What I tried: `sudo chmod -R +w /home/ubuntu/data/stepa/elasticsearch-7.16.2/logs/`. It didn't help.
I didn't succeed to find answer on elastic search forum.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What user you're running it under? Who's current owner and what permissions do `/home/ubuntu/data/stepa/elasticsearch-7.16.2/logs` and `/home/ubuntu/data/stepa/elasticsearch-7.16.2` have?

Comment: whoami: ubuntu,  owner: root,              
/home/ubuntu/data/stepa/elasticsearch-7.16.2/logs: -rw-r--r--  /home/ubuntu/data/stepa/elasticsearch-7.16.2: drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Log lines mean problems with rights. Current user has to be an owner of directory. In my case owner of `/home/ubuntu/data/stepa/elasticsearch-7.16.2/logs/` was root. I changed it using this command `sudo chown username:group /home/ubuntu/data/stepa/elasticsearch-7.16.2/logs`
("ubuntu: " in my case because group is default and username is ubuntu)

Thanks to [ilvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1215136/ilvar) for clues.